# Jquery UI assets management with asset_url

Tags: jquery, user-interface, symfony, assetic

I have a problem with `asset_url` when using jQuery UI because Symfony2 Assetic doesn't found the images.

```
{% macro css(file) %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ file }}" type="text/css" />
{% endmacro %}

{% stylesheets
  '@ClientResultBundle/Resources/public/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css'
   filter='cssrewrite'
%}

{{ imp.css(asset('bundles/clientresult/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css')) }}
```

When I use `asset` only, it seems to work so why not with `asset_url` that is more elegant ,I think (because we can pass several resources at once).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(file) }}" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

your asset url has to be inside the stylesheets block

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    '@ClientResultBundle/Resources/public/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: for more information, read [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for the delay, it seemed to me that i have made all the necessary things to receive notifications of replies by mail but i didn't receive them :/

Comment: Just one thing, i want to use 'jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css' and not '@ClientResultBundle/Resources/public/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css' because it's boring to always put the path. A macro don't seem to work so how can i specify a path ?

Comment: ...and how can i do it right ? It seems that we don't talk of the same thing. This is the macro that i tried to use : `{% macro jsAssetic2(files) %}
  {% set js = '' %}
  {% for file in files %}
    {% set js = js ~ '@ClientResultBundle/Resources/public/js/' ~ file ~ '.js' %}
  {% endfor %}
{% set js = '"'~s~'"' %}
  {% javascripts js|raw %}
    <script src="{{asset_url}}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endmacro %}`